# error while evaluating conditional (restart_status.rc == 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'"}

Tags: ansible

This command fails every time in Ansible
How can I see why that happens and what could be the reason?

```
---
- name:                      "Restart service httpd via service module"
  service:
    name:                    httpd
    state:                   restarted
  register:                  restart_status
  until:                     restart_status.rc == 0
  retries:                   2
  delay:                     10
  when:                      infrastructure_type == 'cloud'
  changed_when:              restart_status.changed
  ignore_errors:             yes
```

Error I get is:

```
error while evaluating conditional (restart_status.rc == 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'"}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because `.rc` is specific to `command:` and `shell:` modules; the [`service:` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) contain no documented output variables, meaning ansible thinks that it can only succeed or fail, but otherwise has nothing more to offer you

Very likely the expression you're after is `until: restart_status is succeeded` using the [`succeeded` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results)

Comment: "Is succeded" will mean it managed to restart the service without errors, right?

Comment: That is actually up to the module itself, but one can only assume that's what `state: restarted` is designed to do, yes. If you find that isn't the case, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues)